# maven: how to specify "systemPath" for dependencied installed locally?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository, local

I've got one myPackage maven project, compiled and installed to local maven repository under

```
~/.m2/repository/mygroup/myPackage/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myPackage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In another maven project, I wish to use it, and in pom.xml I write `<dependency>` section for it. But I don't know how to write the "systemPath" for this jar:

1. I cannot use "~" to specify the path, because "~" is a *nix shell extention, java/maven cannot recognize it.
2. I cannot hard code like

   ```
   /home/myself/.m2/...
   ```

   It's not portable.
3. I cannot use ${project.basedir} because these 2 maven projects are under different folders. But I guess there should be some other maven environment variables that could indicate "home directory"?

All I wish to do is to get this "systemPath" done.

---------------Problem solved by using another project as dependency------------

```
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/../myPackage/pom.xml</systemPath>
```

### That works!

Comment: just creating a dependency in pom.xml should do the job.

Comment: just adding dependency would first check whether it is available at .m2 repository / if you are using any IDE like eclipse you can add jar manually .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A system path is required when the library that your project depends on is not in the maven local repository.

As a rule of thumb, this approach is indeed not portable at all and should be avoided for real projects.

Now, the dependency is in local repository if:

- It was downloaded from some remote repository (usually)
- You've installed it locally (in this case its in your local repository but might not be in your team-mate repo)

In order to install the dependency into the local repo consider using: `mvn install:install-file`+ parameters as written [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

But from your question, it looks like the file is already there... Anyway once the file is in the local repository you can just define a "regular" dependency (group, artifact, version) and Maven will pick it, no need to fiddle with system Path in this case.